# IIS Web Farm with Port

Tags: iis, web, farm

I am trying to create an IIS 8.5 Web Farm for multiple sites i have. Basically i have 2 sites that are defined based on the port ( e.x. 192.168.1.10:5000 and 192.168.1.10:5001 ).

I want to setup a web farm for balancing purposes for those two websites.

I have created two small VMs running the same version of Windows/IIS and with the same configuration ( 192.168.1.100 and 192.168.1.101 ).

When i am setting up the new web farm on my ARR server I can't make the websites, based on the ports to be forwarded and balanced between my two new servers.

For example I am creating a new web farm with a custom http port 5000. When i am requesting 192.168.1.10:5000 i will be redirected under the IIS default website.

any clues?